# Передать согласие или отказ от предоставления личных данных

Tags: android, admob

Здравствуйте я начинающий разработчик, есть приложение на play market, монетизированное с помощью AdMob. Настроил свое диалоговое окно для согласия или отказа на предоставление личных данных, cookies. Не могу понять как передать эти данные в google, admob согласие или отказ от предоставления личных данных. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По дефолту у запроса на рекламу стоит опция PERSONALIZED, что означает -  реклама под юзера, следовательно, передавать что-то гуглу надо только в том случае, если юзер из Европы и отказался от предоставления личных данных. Вот так можно сказать гуглу о том, что ты хочешь получать только NON_PERSONALIZED рекламу:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

Так же хотел бы уточнить по поводу диалогового окна, хоть это не часть вопроса, но всё же регламент серьезный, поэтому решил упомянуть:)

> Note: Google's EU User Consent Policy requires that you collect
>   consent for the full list of ad technology providers configured for
>   your publisher IDs before displaying personalized ads, even if you are
>   using a third-party mediation solution to send ad request to Google.

Заметка выше значит, что, чтобы получить согласие на PERSONALIZED рекламу от всех рекламных нетворков по регламенту, их всех нужно указать в диалоговом окне. И, если используется admob mediation, указать admob недостаточно для получения согласия от юзера по закону. Нужно так же указать все нетворки под капотом у admob mediation.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А если он потом передумает и захочет получать рекламу под юзера, то кадие параметры нужно передать?

Comment: @vitaliy The default behavior of the Google Mobile Ads SDK is to serve personalized ads. Следовательно, просто не передавая этот Bundle, реклама будет персонализированная.

Comment: У меня в настройках admob установлено "Список наиболее часто используемых поставщиков рекламных технологий", мне их нужно перечислить в диалоге?

Comment: @vitaliy вот что пишет гугл: full list of ad technology providers configured for your publisher ID. Для publisher id вы где-то должны были настраивать. По ту сторону не был, тк на работе у нас этим занимается аккаунт менеджер)